# How can I solve this error of cpp file

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
  public:
    int a;
};

void func(int a[])
{
    cout<<a[0]+a[1]+a[2];
}

int main()
{
    a z[3];
    z[0].a=2;
    z[1].a=5;
    z[2].a=7;
    func(z.a);
    return 0;
}
```

this error appears when i compile this program

```
[Error] request for member 'a' in 'z', which is of non-class type 'a [3]'
```

Plz tell me how t solve it

Comment: Learn about indentation. Don't name three things the same name, or you will get confused (the compiler won't)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  The irony here is that it's much less typing to write `std::` in the one place you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `z` is an array.

```
a z[3];
```

Here you are asking for the array's "member `a`".  That's not possible, as `a` is not a member of arrays.  Arrays don't have member variables.

```
func(z.a);
```

This function expects an array of `int`s as a parameter.

```
void func(int a[])
```

You try calling the function.  That's not possible, as you have never created an array of `int`s anywhere in your program.